# Error in running eclipse for android development- "Java was started but returned exit code 13"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have installed adt bundle for android development. I am using Windows 7 32 bit. All the required packages for android have been installed successfully. But after setting up everything I am facing this error while running eclipse "Java was started but returned exit code 13". I have been searching about this error and tried all the possible solutions like setting up environment variables and checking out he java required version compatible with the installed jdk. But I am unable to fix this error. Kindly help me.

Kindly find out the error in png format in the following link:-
http://prminfotech.com/error.png

Comment: You are using a 32 bit Eclipse and a 64 bit Java (or the other way round). They must both be 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: can you post eclipde.ini ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for all your suggestions! I have found my solution. I copied the entire eclipse and sdk folder to C: Drive inside Program Files and now everything is working fine for me.